# XSL lookup from external XML not working from vbscript

Tags: xml, xslt, vbscript

I have an XML file I am transforming where I need to perform a lookup to an external xml.  I believe I have the structure correct, as I have performed this exact same thing elsewhere, but for some reason it will not work here.  The only difference between the two is in this example I am using data from the xml file I am transforming in the lookup, where in the example that works, I am using data from another external XMl file.

My xsl:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
                        extension-element-prefixes="msxsl" >

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="materialLookup" select="document('MaterialLookup.xml')/Materials/Material" />

    <xsl:template match="Report[@schema='1.0']">
        <Job>
            <Job_Number><xsl:value-of select="DocumentProperties/title"/></Job_Number>
            <Benchtops>
            <xsl:for-each select="Item[Type='Benchtop' and Properties/bench_material_brand='Stone' and Properties/granite_supplier='Claytons']" >
                <xsl:sort select="PageName"/>
                <Benchtop>

                    <Material><xsl:value-of select="$materialLookup[cmCode = Properties/bench_material_color]/dmCode"/></Material>
                    <Colour><xsl:value-of select="Properties/bench_material_color"/></Colour>

                </Benchtop>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </Benchtops>
        </Job>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Report schema="1.0">  
  <Item id="91" name="Cabinet">
    <Page>1</Page>
    <PageName>Page 1</PageName>
    <Type>Benchtop</Type>
    <SubType>Benchtop</SubType>
    <Code>Benchtop</Code>
    <Desc>TOP GT600</Desc>
    <Label>TOP(91)</Label>
    <Properties>
      <top_sequence_letter>91</top_sequence_letter>
      <bench_material_brand>Stone</bench_material_brand>
      <bench_material_color>C4-Milano Mist</bench_material_color>
      <bench_material_finish></bench_material_finish>
      <top_granite_thickness>40mm</top_granite_thickness>
      <granite_supplier>Claytons</granite_supplier>
  <DocumentProperties>
    <documenttitle>B98582</documenttitle>
  </DocumentProperties>
</Report>
```

And the XML lookup for MaterialLookup.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Materials xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
  <Material>
    <cmCode>C4-Milano Mist</cmCode>
    <dmCode>MAT01000399</dmCode>
    <dmDescription>Essa Stone Milano Mist</dmDescription>
  </Material>
  <Material>
    <cmCode>C4-Verona Mist</cmCode>
    <dmCode>MAT01000382</dmCode>
    <dmDescription>Essa Stone Verona Mist</dmDescription>
  </Material>
  <Material>
    <cmCode>ES-Arcardia</cmCode>
    <dmCode>MAT01000211</dmCode>
    <dmDescription>Smart Stone Arcadia 012501</dmDescription>
  </Material>
</Materials>
```

I have tried pretty much everything I can think of, and I know it's going to be something really simple that I have overlooked, but for the moment I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `current()` in `<xsl:value-of select="$materialLookup[cmCode = current()/Properties/bench_material_color]/dmCode"/>`.

Here are complete samples, the primary input is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Report schema="1.0">  
    <Item id="91" name="Cabinet">
        <Page>1</Page>
        <PageName>Page 1</PageName>
        <Type>Benchtop</Type>
        <SubType>Benchtop</SubType>
        <Code>Benchtop</Code>
        <Desc>TOP GT600</Desc>
        <Label>TOP(91)</Label>
        <Properties>
            <top_sequence_letter>91</top_sequence_letter>
            <bench_material_brand>Stone</bench_material_brand>
            <bench_material_color>C4-Milano Mist</bench_material_color>
            <bench_material_finish></bench_material_finish>
            <top_granite_thickness>40mm</top_granite_thickness>
            <granite_supplier>Claytons</granite_supplier>
            <DocumentProperties>
                <documenttitle>B98582</documenttitle>
            </DocumentProperties>
        </Properties>
    </Item>
</Report>
```

the secondary document is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Materials xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
    <Material>
        <cmCode>C4-Milano Mist</cmCode>
        <dmCode>MAT01000399</dmCode>
        <dmDescription>Essa Stone Milano Mist</dmDescription>
    </Material>
    <Material>
        <cmCode>C4-Verona Mist</cmCode>
        <dmCode>MAT01000382</dmCode>
        <dmDescription>Essa Stone Verona Mist</dmDescription>
    </Material>
    <Material>
        <cmCode>ES-Arcardia</cmCode>
        <dmCode>MAT01000211</dmCode>
        <dmDescription>Smart Stone Arcadia 012501</dmDescription>
    </Material>
</Materials>
```

and the result I get is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Job>
   <Job_Number/>
   <Benchtops>
      <Benchtop>
         <Material>MAT01000399</Material>
         <Colour>C4-Milano Mist</Colour>
      </Benchtop>
   </Benchtops>
</Job>
```

when I run the stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    extension-element-prefixes="msxsl" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="materialLookup" select="document('test2016072102.xml')/Materials/Material" />

    <xsl:template match="Report[@schema='1.0']">
        <Job>
            <Job_Number><xsl:value-of select="DocumentProperties/title"/></Job_Number>
            <Benchtops>
                <xsl:for-each select="Item[Type='Benchtop' and Properties/bench_material_brand='Stone' and Properties/granite_supplier='Claytons']" >
                    <xsl:sort select="PageName"/>
                    <Benchtop>

                        <Material><xsl:value-of select="$materialLookup[cmCode = current()/Properties/bench_material_color]/dmCode"/></Material>
                        <Colour><xsl:value-of select="Properties/bench_material_color"/></Colour>

                    </Benchtop>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Benchtops>
        </Job>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: When I include current(), the result is no different.  It still fails.

Comment: @paularmy42, I have edited the answer with full samples, I think the referenced data is found.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I have re-created all files exactly as you have them and it still failed, so I tried running the transform through an editor and it worked!  I have previously been performing the transform using a vbscript, which is where it fails.  The error I get is **allowdocumentfunction constraint violated** .  Perhaps this is a vb issue rather than a xsl issue?

Comment: Edit your question and add a tag for vbscript (or vb, I am not sure what you use) and then of course add the code you use to run the XSLT transformation. If you use MSXML 6 with VBScript then I think you need to make sure to set `xslDoc.setProperty "AllowDocumentFunction", True` on the DOM document you use to load the XSLT code. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762664(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: that was it.  I feel so stupid!  `xslDoc.setProperty "AllowDocumentFunction", True` was missing from the one line that it mattered on.  I'll mark your answer as accepted.  Thanks for your help.